# converting postman json code to python at locust

Tags: python, postman, locust

I m trying to make a converter that automatically converts the json object to python that comes up when exporting after clicking a request in postman.

GET PUT POST methoths are there
how can i define data Imagine you have 100 requests

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, between # kütüphanesinden içe aktarıyoruz. 
import json

class MyUser(HttpUser): # Locust senaryolarını tanımlamak için kullanılan temel sınıftır
    wait_time = between(1, 5)  # Kullanıcıların her istek arasında bekleme süresi

    @task #bir işlemi veya görevi temsil etmek için kullanılan
    def update_post(self):
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"} #değişkeni, isteğe eklenen başlıkları belirtir Bu örnekte, JSON verisi göndereceğimiz için "Content-Type" başlığını "application/json" olarak ayarlıyoruz.
        payload = { 
            "title": "New Title",
            "body": "Updated body content"
        } #adında bir sözlük tanımlanıyor. Bu sözlük, güncellenecek gönderi verilerini içerir.
        response = self.client.put("/update-post-endpoint", data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers) #metodunu kullanarak belirtilen URL'ye JSON verilerini içeren bir PUT isteği gönderirken elde edilen cevabı saklar.veri eklemek için kullanılır.
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("basarili bir sekilde guncellendi")
            updated_post_data = response.json()
            print("basarili guncellendi",updated_post_data)
        else:
            print("guncelemede basarızızlık - Status Code:", response.status_code)
            print("Response:", response.text)
    @task
    def get_post(self):
        response = self.client.get("/get-post-endpoint")
        if response.status_code==200:
         
            print("basirili bir sekilde alındı")
            json_data = response.json() 
            print("alındı JSON data:", json_data)
        else:
            print("hata -Status Code:",response.status_code)
            print(response.text)
```

Comment: Parts of your code are in… I’m guessing turkish? Probably best to translate it to english before posting here :) But if you’re looking for a place to start, look at har2locust. It does pretty much the same thing, but for browser recordings/HAR files. https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/har2locust